# Studies about stereotypes' accuracy of different genre listeners

Tags: history, genre

We all have in mind when we think of a typical metal listener a person wearing black clothes, long haired, with big black boots and etc. For almost each genre, there exist stereotypes of the typical listener.

So I asked myself two questions:

- Has anyone ever studied those stereotypes and their accuracy, sociologicaly or statisticaly speaking?
- When did those stereotypes appear? I mean in which context, and why did they appear?

I was thinking specifically about the example of people listening to metal first, but the topic can be widened!

Comment: Well, I am the perfect example that even lovers of hard and heavy metal can just look like a normal person. No black leather, no metal spikes and chains, no weird haircut, just a normal young guy... ;D

Comment: @ByteCommander It's funny, I am a metal fan myself and know a lot of other metal fans and none of us fit the stereotype. In fact, I don't think I've ever met a metal fan who did.

Comment: @DJAftershock Well, I saw some from the distance, so they really exist, but I don't know anybody in person... Though I would like to ;D

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question particularly focused on music. Stereotypes apply to all sorts of aspects of people's behaviors and preferences. This is more of a general sociology question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The British site [YouGov](https://yougov.co.uk/profiler#/) runs surveys online and via mobile.
They recently released a 'profiler' service on the site that links basically anything to anything. In other words, you can enter a band name and receive other information on the people who 'liked' that band.

For example Fans of AC/DC are mainly 
<sub>[source](https://yougov.co.uk/profileslite#/AC_DC/demographics)</sub>

- Male
- 40-59
- Live in Central Scotland, Northern Scotland & North East England
- Professions: Engineering, Manufacturing, Military
- Monthly spare income - £125

Based on 4700+ 'likes'

And, Fans of Hozier are mainly
 <sub>[source](https://yougov.co.uk/profileslite#/Hozier/demographics)</sub>

- Female
- 18-24
- Live in London, West Country, Central Scotland
- Professions: Insurance, Real estate, Advertising
- Monthly spare income £125 - £499

Based on 998 'likes'

While this isn't a scientific study it does reveal some interesting correlations of data.

Comment: The "source" links don't seem to match any more, perhaps the YouGov website has changed their search function. Could you check it please?

Answer (score 4):

This news piece made quite a splash in Europe some years back:

> [The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/3352230/Heavy-metal-a-comfort-for-the-bright-child.html)
>   **Heavy metal 'a comfort for the bright child'**
>
> Intelligent teenagers often listen to heavy metal music to cope with
>   the pressures associated with being talented, according to research.
>
> The results of a study of more than 1,000 of the brightest five per
>   cent of young people will come as relief to parents whose offspring,
>   usually long-haired, are devotees of Iron Maiden, AC/DC and their
>   musical descendants.
>
> Researchers found that, far from being a sign of delinquency and poor
>   academic ability, many adolescent "metalheads" are extremely bright
>   and often use the music to help them deal with the stresses and
>   strains of being gifted social outsiders.

Up until this study was published many parents still thought of heavy music as a danger with deviant risks. It turns out to be a simple reflex of a certain type of social pressure.

Answer (score 4):

Frontiers in Human Neuroscience just published an article with insteresting conclusions regarding folk that listen to heavy music:

[**Extreme metal music and anger processing**](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fnhum.2015.00272/full)

*Leah Sharman and Genevieve A. Dingle*

> The claim that listening to extreme music causes anger, and
>   expressions of anger such as aggression and delinquency have yet to be
>   substantiated using controlled experimental methods. In this study, 39
>   extreme music listeners aged 18–34 years were subjected to an anger
>   induction, followed by random assignment to 10 min of listening to
>   extreme music from their own playlist, or 10 min silence (control).
>   Measures of emotion included heart rate and subjective ratings on the
>   Positive and Negative Affect Scale (PANAS). Results showed that
>   ratings of PANAS hostility, irritability, and stress increased during
>   the anger induction, and decreased after the music or silence. Heart
>   rate increased during the anger induction and was sustained (not
>   increased) in the music condition, and decreased in the silence
>   condition. PANAS active and inspired ratings increased during music
>   listening, an effect that was not seen in controls. The findings
>   indicate that extreme music did not make angry participants angrier;
>   rather, it appeared to match their physiological arousal and result in
>   an increase in positive emotions. Listening to extreme music may
>   represent a healthy way of processing anger for these listeners.

Answer (score 3):

There is a pretty well-respected sociological study of heavy metal from 1991 by Deena Weinstein, *Heavy Metal:  A Cultural Sociology.*  She covers the roots (hippie "longhair" culture) and the belief structures (strongly masculine, anti-establishment, fatalist, chaos-worshipping) of the metal subculture. It's an excellent book.